# Basic question regarding power consumption of different devices

Tags: power-supply, power, voltage, current, dc

I have current values for devices measured at different DC voltages.

- 4.2mA at 2.4V
- 68.8uA at 3.0V
- 44mA at 2.0V
- 65mA at 3.4V

If I were to power them at a voltage of 3.6V and would like to estimate the current for each device at this voltage, what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: This question if far from clear.  What are these devices?  How do the currents flow?  Schematic, block diagram?  Why do you want to estimate current?  What are you aiming to achieve?

Comment: Apologies, currently programming a small embedded systems project where I have many sensors connected to a microcontroller. All sensors & microcontroller have an operating voltage range from about 1.8v to 5 and I am going to power them all from a 3.6v supply which comprises of a lithium polymer battery and regulator. The values I have given are that of "typical consumption" which is in a datasheet for each sensor. I would like to estimate battery life as best I can before I purchase the components however to do this I need current flowing at for each at 3.6v.

Comment: Without knowing the technology of each device (and whether they are suitable for 3.6V) it is impossible to answer. So, to steal part of Nick's comment, what are these devices and by "what" I mean provide data sheets.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the appropriate *linear* regulator to power each device, the total current draw at 3.6V will be the total of the currents you measured, plus the quiescent currents of the regulators themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given enough information to answer the question. For some devices the current draw will be linearly proportional to the supply voltage, for some the current will be proportional to the square of the supply voltage, and some devices could exhibit different behavior altogether. In other words, you can't extrapolate the current at one voltage to a higher voltage without knowing the characteristics of the device.